# How to change behavior of Echo or turn it off without removing it from code?

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, output-formatting, options, optional-arguments

I wish to use `Echo` for output of intermediate results if an `OptionValue` I call `verbose->True` and neutralize it if `verbose->False`. I think this is useful when you need to know if some resources (packages. etc) were successfully loaded. I am thinking that it might work one of two ways...

1. Spot lines of code with Echo but if `verbose->False` turn off Echo inside function then turn Echo back on when leaving function.
2. Spot lines of code with a generic `fn` variable. When `verbose->True` activate it with `fn=Echo` but in its off state it should do something completely inert `fn=do-something-that-does-not-effect-expression`.

Please help me figure this out. Here is where I would first use it. Notice the `If` statements that really do nothing more than repeat an Echo wrapped expression. I wish to eliminate the `If` statements.

```
$resources=windows-path-to-alternate-directory-for-packages
packs={"package1`","package2`",...}
Options[loadPacks] = {path -> $resources, verbose -> True};
loadPacks[packs_, OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{pathslist},
   addpath[] := Once[PrependTo[$Path, OptionValue[path]]];
   If[OptionValue[verbose] === True, Echo[addpath[]], addpath[]];
   Map[Needs[#] &, packs];
   If[OptionValue[verbose] === True, 
    Echo[Column[contextSymbols[packs]]], Return[]];
   ];
contextSymbols[names__] := 
  Block[{list}, list = If[ListQ[names], names, {names}]; 
   Map[Names[# <> "*"] &, list]];
```

Comment: Consider using your own `echo` function in the code. Then at the beginning of your function, you can set its value to `Echo` or `Identity` depending on the value of the option.

Comment: @MarcoB I had already figured it out but I called my "echo" `echoResults[expr,label,show->opt]` where if `show ->True` (this is default) will do `Echo[expr,label]` but if show anything else it returns Evaluate[expr]. Is this potentially problematic? Is `Identity` a safer option? should I allow for a third option on `show ->Echo, Identity, or Evaluate`?  I can count maybe a dozen times you helped me. Thank you so much. :)